# Create variable from array keys in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables

Is there a way to make a variable using an array value?  For ex.

```
//Define all Notes in Sharps and Flats
var noteSharp = ["A","A#","B","C","C#","D","D#","E","F","F#","G","G#"];
var noteFlat = ["A","Bb","B","C","Db","D","Eb","E","F","Gb","G","Ab"];

//Make all Major Scales
for (var x=0; x<12; x++){
var noteSharp[x] + "Sharp" = noteSharp[x] + noteSharp[x+2] + noteSharp[x+4] + noteSharp[x+5] + noteSharp[x+7] + noteSharp[x+9] + noteSharp[x+11];
var noteFlat[x] + "Flat" = noteFlat[x] + noteFlat[x+2] + noteFlat[x+4] + noteFlat[x+5] + noteFlat[x+7] + noteFlat[x+9] + noteFlat[x+11];
}
```

If I do a console.log(CSharp) it says that CSharp is not defined.

In this example I am trying to define a total of 24 variables.  Some variable name examples im expecting to get are ASharp , A#Sharp , BbFlat , DFlat.  The CSharp and CFlat variable should both be "CDEFGAB"

If this is not possible is it because variables have to be defined before the javascript file is read by the browser at run-time for memory leak security.

Comment: That looks like a really bad idea

Comment: It's better to just stick with arrays than to make lots and lots of variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to make a global variable, attach it to `window`

```
window[variableNameHere] = itsValue;
```

In your case:

```
window[noteSharp[x] + "Sharp"] = noteSharp[x] + ...
```

But it's not good to pollute the global namespace. How about putting it in another namespace:

```
var sharps = {};
var flats = {};
sharps[noteSharp[x] + "Sharp"] = noteSharp[x]...
flats[noteFlat[x] + "Sharp"] = noteFlat[x]...

//access them
sharps.ASharp;
```

I quite can't figure out what your code does, but this solution should point you to the right direction.

Comment: I like your approach on dynamically naming a variable and having it global.

Comment: @ManofSnow: Just curious here how to access 'A#' ? I am getting '"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL' error when accessing  "sharps.A#Sharp". Looks like '#' is culprit.

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick response.  That helped immensely Joseph.  The last question on that is, is this a bad practice or maybe a better way of doing this?

Also just if you were wondering, this is for music.  It will make every major scale using sharps or flats.  I will evuentally have a record of every chord and make it so that a user can type any notes and the program will shoot out all of the possible chord types that could be made with those notes.

Comment: @budhram Since it has `#`, an illegal character for naming, use the bracket notation instead: `namespace['sharps.A#Sharp']`.

Comment: @user3148364 I suggest you try this solution first, and if you come across any problems that code, you can post another question here at StackOverflow.

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer: Thanks. Bracket notation works :). Used "sharps['A#Sharp']" to access 'A#'.

Answer (score 0):

Change the end of your code to look like this:

```
for (var x=0; x<12; x++){
    self[noteSharp[x] + "Sharp"] = noteSharp[x] + noteSharp[x+2] + noteSharp[x+4] + noteSharp[x+5] + noteSharp[x+7] + noteSharp[x+9] + noteSharp[x+11];
    self[noteFlat[x] + "Flat"] = noteFlat[x] + noteFlat[x+2] + noteFlat[x+4] + noteFlat[x+5] + noteFlat[x+7] + noteFlat[x+9] + noteFlat[x+11];
}
```

As a result, you will have global variables with variable names like you want, such as CSharp, which would equal "CDEFGAB"--however, complicated variable names like `A#Sharp` cannot be written outright as variables, but can still be accessed by using subscript notation, like this `self["A#Sharp"]` (or `window["A#Sharp"]` in most cases, although it has traditionally been better style to use `self` rather than `window` to refer to the most local window object connected with a script instance).

The other answer looks like it has been finished out by the time I finished typing mine, and it looks good, too.

Comment: What is *self*? Where was it defined?

Comment: Part of `window` are the global properties like `alert` and `self`. Few write `window.alert`, however, and few write `window.self` unless there is a difference between them, such as when in a frame and checking whether `window.top != window.self`. It is better to use `self` than window when creating global variables to avoid polluting more global namespaces, because, although in most cases it is the same, there are rare instances where self is a more local copy of window than window.

Comment: Thanks for that insight i totally forgot that, # cant be a used in a variable

Answer (score 0):

try the following code

```
var noteSharp = ["A","B","C"];
for(i in noteSharp) {
 window[noteSharp[i]] = 'value of '+noteSharp[i];
}


alert(A)
alert(B)
alert(C)
```

This is exactly what you want.

and rewriting it for your code

```
//Define all Notes in Sharps and Flats
var noteSharp = ["A","A#","B","C","C#","D","D#","E","F","F#","G","G#"];
var noteFlat = ["A","Bb","B","C","Db","D","Eb","E","F","Gb","G","Ab"];

//Make all Major Scales
for (var x=0; x<12; x++){
window[noteSharp[x] + "Sharp"] = noteSharp[x] + noteSharp[x+2] + noteSharp[x+4] + noteSharp[x+5] + noteSharp[x+7] + noteSharp[x+9] + noteSharp[x+11];
window[noteFlat[x] + "Flat"] = noteFlat[x] + noteFlat[x+2] + noteFlat[x+4] + noteFlat[x+5] + noteFlat[x+7] + noteFlat[x+9] + noteFlat[x+11];
}

alert(ASharp);
alert(AFlat);
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, in JavaScript there are 2 ways by which you can create dynamic variables:

- eval Function
- window object

**eval:**

```
var times = 1;
eval("var sum" + times + "=10;");
alert(sum1);
```

**window object:**

```
var times = 1;
window["sum" + times] = 10;
alert(window["sum1"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

> If this is not possible

It isn't for local variables without the use of *eval*.

> is it because variables have to be defined before the javascript file is read by the browser at run-time for memory leak security.

No. It's not possible because ECMA-262 specifies that the only way to declare a variable is by a [variable declaration statement](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.2), which is of the form:

```
var *identifier* [optional initialiser]
```

where *identifier* is a valid identifier, which can't be an expression like:

```
var 'foo' + 'bar';
```

The rest of the question has been covered in other answers.